# Job not returning PSObject

Tags: powershell, jobs

Can someone explain why this job isn't returning anything?  The object gets created and returned when it's not run in a job.  I am not sure what might be going wrong.

```
$verifyJob = {

$prm = @{'ComputerName' = $args[0];'Credential' = $args[1]}
$esc = @{'ErrorAction' = 'SilentlyContinue'}

# IP Address
$IPAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($args[0]).IPAddressToString

# WMI queries
$os = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem @prm @esc
$cs = gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem @prm @esc

[pscustomobject]@{
    ComputerName = $args[0]
    OSVersion = $os.Version.SubString(0,3)
    Domain = $cs.Domain.Split(".")[0]
    IP = $IPAddress
    }
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $verifyJob -ArgumentList [server],[cred]
Get-Job |Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

When I receive the job, there is nothing there.  I have tried assigning the object to a variable and returning it at the end of the job, but no luck there either.

*edited for Wait-Job clarity

Comment: Did you try to use `Wait-Job`?

Comment: I didn't, but I was running everything manually.  I did wait to receive the job until it was showing as complete.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the job to complete to get the results.

From [`Receive-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/78fcc10b-5cde-4bf2-a901-33f8237f87fe%28v=wps.630%29.aspx):

> The Receive-Job cmdlet gets the results that have been generated by the time that the Receive-Job command is submitted. If the results are not yet complete, you can run additional Receive-Job commands to get the remaining results.

Given WMI queries can take a a while to run I suspect you need to perform a [`Wait-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849735%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) to allow it to complete.

Note also the results of `Get-Job` will tell you the job's status and whether there is data waiting to be received.

Comment: I did address this above.  I was running this manually.  The job was complete when I received it.

Comment: @Acerbity OK, I think I just missed that comment. I also note you think this is not the problem, but as the general initial answer to this I'll leave this in place for others.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out the code as I posted it is working correctly.  My actual script is very long and there is likely a separate error causing my issues.